# Examples of non-predefined pl/sql exceptions?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, exception, plsql

Is there any site that have the list of non-predefined oracle server error? 
The predefined errors are easy to find (zero_divide, no_data_found etc.) but the non-predefined, i can't find a list of it.

So i would like to ask if those errors are really not searchable in the internet that the only way i would know them is when i encounter them.

suggestions anyone?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are in the documentation, with a different set for each version.

Here's 11gR2: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/lookup?id=ERRMG